# "dos: Memory allocation error" while loading 'mingw-0.9.3-0'

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, mingw, scilab

"dos: Memory allocation error" occurs while loading 'mingw-0.9.3-0' on Scilab 5.5.2.
How can I get rid of these messages?

ATOMS (Scilab's Module Manager) prompted me to install MinGW because some Scilab demos are available only when gcc is installed.
My Machine is 64-bit Windows10 and my Scilab is also a 64-bit version, so I chose a 64-bit version of MinGW.
After that, I installed the interface between them through ATOMS, and restarted Scilab. Then, I got this message:

```
Startup execution:
  loading initial environment

Mingw Compiler support for Scilab
    Load macros
Warning !!!
Scilab has found a critical error (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
with "stacksize" function.
Save your data and restart Scilab.
Converting Libraries.
Build libblasplus.a
atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'mingw-0.9.3-0':
    dos: Memory allocation error.
```

... I searched a solution and all I found is this thread:
https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw

Although their error messages (Undefined operation) are different from mine (Memory allocation error), this seems to be a bug which has not been fixed yet. Incidentally, I already started Scilab with "Run as Administrator" option and no luck. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also fighting with this problem for a while. Seems to be a incompatibility of the stacksize function on win10 machines.

This fix is working for me:

- Find the mingw.start file, it is probably in the directory "scilab-5.5.2\contrib\mingw\0.9.3-0\etc".
- Comment out the row #49 with the stacksize('max') order by placing "//" in front of the row
- Start scilab, at the first run scilab builds up some libs with mingw so it needs more time than usual

Comment: Solved, thanks to your suggestion. Firstly, I commented out the "stacksize('max')", but it didn't work for me. Next, I figured out the "stacksize(10e6)" is an acceptable stacksize for my PC (RAM=8GB). (As you know, you can type "stacksize(10e6)" on console and check if it works.) Then, I run "loader.sce" in mingw_0.9.3, and restarted Scilab ... I guess. As you said, many libs were loaded and built. Now, all demos work! Thank you very much!!!